# how to achieve .eq(-1) in jQuery older than 1.4?

Tags: jquery

```
$(selector).eq(-1)
```

I spent some time to find why the above script doesn't work for me,

it's because I'm not using jQuery 1.4

How to achieve the same in older jQuery?

Comment: And what about all your older questions? No useful answers? ;)

Comment: Most of them are because SO doesn't allow to accept,but to wait for several minutes,and after that period I forgot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var sLen = $(selector).length;
$(selector).eq(sLen-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var es = $(selector);
```

and then

```
es.get(es.length - 1)
```